# Generify codeurl in template.yml for aws lambda function local testing

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-serverless

I have a lambda function and its template.yml looks like this

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31

Resources:
  ExampleJavaFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      Handler: com.someCompany.SNSListener::handleRequest
      CodeUri: ./target/aws-lambda-sqs-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
      Runtime: java8
```

and I use sam-local to test lambda function locally, like this

```
sam local invoke --event event_file.json
```

But the problem if you see here is, we need to update CodeUri every time we update version of maven, can we make this generic? I tried using * but it did not work